# Contact Form 7 JS Load Time and Elements

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance, pagespeed, contact-form-7

I am having trouble with Contact Form 7 Wordpress Plugin generating multiple request on page load that I think are slowing down my site. See image below:

[Gtmetrix Waterfall Results for marquesolivia.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVsr5.png)

There are nearly 30 processes loaded by CF7 that stack and end up slowing the page load by more than 4 seconds. Is this normal? How it can be solved? Anyone with a similar issue?

Elements loaded are strings like this:

http://marquesolivia.com/?_wpcf7_is_ajax_call=1&_wpcf7=9618&_wpcf7_request_ver=1485939253183

Thanks in advance!

Have all a nice day.